# ¿Cómo 'bajar' de a 1 segundo a la vez?

Tags: javascript

```
let num = parseInt(prompt('Ingresa un numero'));
 for (i= num; i > 0; --i) {
   console.log(`Baja: ${i}`);
 }
```

Comment: Puedes usar `setTimeOut`

Answer (score 1):

Vas a tener que trabajar con las funciones de intervalo de Javascript.

`setInterval` toma como primer argumento una funcion y como segundo, la cantidad de milisegundos que deseas esperar antes de que se vuelva a invocar la funcion nuevamente. Para llamar una funcion cada un segundo seria algo como esto

```javascript
setInterval(() => console.log('Hola'), 1000);
```

Si asignas el `setInterval` a una variable, luego puedes llamar `clearInterval()` sobre esa variable para limpiar el intervalo y que se deje de llamar.

```javascript
let num = 10;

const interval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(num);
    num--;
    if (num === 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Espero que te sirva